# ionic promise and storage

Tags: ionic-framework, promise, ionic3

how to return the API call after storage was set or error found?
From the console.log, **seq** was always returned before the **Token Stored**.

My desired sequence are:

1. User submit the form using the function **SubmitForm()**.
2. The function call another function in **user.ts** page and if the user authentication success, login.ts page will pop.
3. The **user.ts** currently handles the api call and set the storage (if authentication success). The storage was always delayed after the checking of isLoggedIn (in login.ts page) was called therefore not able to pop.

**login.ts**

```
SubmitForm(account: any) {
    this.user.login(account).subscribe((resp) => {
        if(this.user.isLoggedIn){
          this.navCtrl.pop();
        }
    }, (err) => {

    });
}
```

**user.ts (user provider)**

```
login(logininfo: any) {
    let seq = this.api.post('auth/login', logininfo).share();

    seq.subscribe((res: any) => {
      if (res.status == 'success') {
        this.storage.set('token', res.token).then(data => {
          console.log('Token Stored', data); //This always get called after `return seq;`
          this.token = data;
          this.isLoggedIn = true;
        },
        error => {
          console.log('Error storing token', error);
        });
      }
    }, err => {
      console.error('ERROR', err);
    });

    return seq; //This always called before the token was stored
}
```

Comment: you need to use async/await in your method

Answer (score 0):

When you have a function like yours and you need to 'wait for asynchronous functions inside it to finish' you need to use async/await. Basically this wraps your entire function into one Promise which is then returned. An async function always automatically returns a Promise.

Something like this could work, however I am not quite sure about your code as you only supplied a snippet. If you supply a codesandbox, I can take a deeper look at it.

```
  async login(logininfo: any) {
    let seq = this.api.post('auth/login', logininfo);

    let returnValue = undefined;
    let subscription = await seq.subscribe(async (res: any) => {
      if (res.status == 'success') {
        returnValue = await this.storage.set('token', res.token).then(data => {
          console.log('Token Stored', data); //This always get called after `return seq;`
        },
        error => {
          console.log('Error storing token', error);
        });
      }
    }, err => {
      console.error('ERROR', err);
    });

    return returnValue; //This always returns a promise
  }
```

Comment: Hi, I have added my login.ts page. Lets say the authentication success, but the navCtrl never pop due to isLoggedIn not yet set to true. And the reason it did not set to true is due to the storage not yet set it.

Comment: You need to use async/await if you wish to work with promises. For cases like these while it's looked at with a bad eye you can also simply pass your login object and then call a method such as .afterLogin() after you are done storing your object. so your login method call would be login(account, this)